# Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. asBitmap() red color error

Tags: java, android-bitmap, android-glide

I'm getting a compile error as asBitmap is showing in red text error color, please help me to fix the issue.
code below:

```
 try {
        Bitmap bitmap = Glide.with(this).load(url).asBitmap().into(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL).get();
        if (bitmap != null) {
            if (wallpaper) {
                setAsWallpaper(bitmap);
            } else {
                saveImage(bitmap);
            }
        } else {
            failure();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: asBitmap() is in red color.

Comment: error: cannot find symbol method asBitmap()

Comment: Check out the solutions to the above duplicate question.